# compadd doesn't work when called from nested functions

Tags: zsh, kubectl, zsh-completion

I have some custom completion I've been working on and am stuck. It extends existing completion scripts with some custom options. The full file can be found here https://github.com/rothgar/k/blob/zsh-completion/completions/zsh/k

I have a custom function called `__k_handle_kspace` which looks at the current word and does a basic case statement and calls another function. (pasting code without comments and extra options here)

```
__k_handle_kspace() {
    cur="${words[$CURRENT]}"

    case $cur in
    +* )
        __k_kspace_parse_config_contexts
        ;;
    @* )
        __k_kspace_parse_config_clusters
esac
```

When I set `compdef __k_handle_kspace k` this works great and all tab completion is exactly what I want. The full `__k_kspace_parse_config_*` function can be found [here](https://github.com/rothgar/k/blob/zsh-completion/completions/zsh/k#L13-L46)

The completion by default uses `__start_k` which calls `__k_handle_word` which then calls my `__k_handle_kspace` function.

When I set `compdef __start_k k` I can see my functions being called (using `set -x` for debugging) and `compadd` being the last thing called but no tab completion is shown.

When I use the default completion I also have to change the cur variable to `cur="${words[$(($CURRENT -1))]}"` in my `__k_handle_kspace` function.

I cant figure out if there's a variable I need to set/return from my function or rules around when `compadd` can be called to return completion values.

---

Comment: Can you add the last lines of output from `set -x`, so we can see what's happening? That would help.

Comment: I found out from the zsh-workers mailing list that the reason it was happening was from a default completion that tries to complete files after my custom completion ran. I used https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Base/Widget/_complete_debug  and saw it would run _bash_complete which looked for files that started with `@` `:` or `+`. I haven't figure out how to stop _bash_complete from running yet (maybe zstyle) but hope to start looking at it again soon.

Comment: You wrote "no tab completion is shown". How can no tab completion be shown because a default completion is run? That doesn't make any sense. Can you share a bit more of the conversation on the mailing list?

Comment: Also, there is no completer called `_bash_complete`. I presume you mean [`_bash_completions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fbash_005fcompletions)? That's actually a top-level widget function. You are reading the output of [`^Xh`](index-_005fcomplete_005fhelp-_0028_005eXh_0029) the wrong way around. `_bash_completions` is apparently the widget function you've bound to your tab key.

Comment: Anyway, again, it would be helpful if you could actually show the output of `set -x` or `^Xh`. It would make it a lot easier to help you if you did.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. Using _complete_debug widget here's the full output of `k @<tab>` https://gist.github.com/rothgar/249cc731eafc3a58b6dd24eaeb517bf3 You'll see at line 355 `compadd` adds the clusters to completion I would expect but then line 384 the zstyle tries to complete files that start with `@` and line 2173 says no matches found. If I put a file called `@foo` in the directory it'll match that file

Comment: I think I need to modify the zstyle of the command to ignore files when using `:`, `+`, or `@` but I haven't figure out how to do that yet. Otherwise the completion looks like it works as intended.

Comment: Ah, now I found where `_bash_complete` comes from: You're using `bashcompinit`. But if you're writing completion function for Zsh natively, then why are you using `_bash_complete`? You write that you've used `compdef __k_handle_kspace k`, but it looks like you've actually used `bashcompinit`'s `complete` function instead.

Comment: The output from `kubctl autocomelpte zsh` enables bashcompinit because it is required for many of the functions. I've extended the default output to handle my specific arguments. I believe this behavior comes from cobra (the go cli framework). https://github.com/rothgar/k/blob/zsh-completion/completions/zsh/k#L212 I'm not sure if there's a way for me to disable bashcompinit for specific functions so they don't use `_bash_complete` or if I would have to change the behavior of kubectl's completion function. I thought `zstyle` might be able to do that but maybe I'm probably wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion code you're extending is based on `bashcompinit`. As a result of this, you need to write your code as a *Bash* completion function. This means you should add your completion matches to the [array `COMPREPLY`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/77d203f3fbbd76386bf197f9776269a1de580bb5/Completion/bashcompinit#L123). Because that array is empty when your function returns, `_bash_complete` reports to Zsh's `_main_complete` that it has failed.

So, in short: Add your completion matches to `COMPREPLY`, instead of using `compadd`, and that should fix it.

Comment: Sadly you're right. Until I can remove the bashcompinit dependency I won't be able to get it working the way I want.